# Replacement for xamarin.inappbilling component on Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using the old [Xamarin.InappBilling component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inappbilling?version=1.1) in my Android app. Xamarin has now announced that [components are migrating to NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/component-nuget?tabs=vswin). What is the migration path for this particular component, i.e.

```
Xamarin.InAppBilling.Product
```

I have not been using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I would look at James Montemagno's plugin: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin (It supports Android API-14+) and is an active project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, face it. `Xamarin.InAppBilling` is gone with the Xamarin Component Store as Microsoft [announced](https://blog.xamarin.com/hello-nuget-new-home-xamarin-components/) earlier. And as of now,  `Xamarin.InAppBilling` is not available on the NuGet Gallery.

I recommend switching to James Montemagno's [InAppBilling Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.InAppBilling/). I recently had to do this and trust me, it's a hell lot simpler and easier to implement. The API is pretty straightforward in making purchases and error handling, whereas previously in `Xamarin.InAppBilling`, you had to handle around 5-6 events for making a purchase..